# How to fix error: A value of type 'User?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'User'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I am a beginner in app development and am having trouble with this error.
The error I get is "error: A value of type 'User?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'User'."

My Code:

```
Future signUpWithEmailAndPassword( String email, String password) async {
    try {
      UserCredential result = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      User user = result.user;
      return _userFromFirebaseUser(user);
    } catch(e){
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 9):

change the line

```
User user = result.user;
```

to

```
User? user = result.user;
```

Answer (score 5):

You can actually fix that error by using `!`. But make sure that `result.user` is not null!

```
User user = result.user!;
```

Comment: Exactly: The `?` in `User?` indicates that the value may be null, so ensuring that user is defined resolves the issue

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

**1.** *Right-click* the line which has the error

**2.** Click on *more options*

**3.** Click on *Add cast*

Watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WdaGKvuBsII) tutorial for connecting Firebase with your Flutter app